# Dependency Service and passing values between droid and standard project

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have a method that need to use native droid functions. I am using Dependency services to achieve that which is fine, however i also need to send a value that gets filled in my standard project.When debugging i see the value in the standard however once i enter droid the value is null i have also tried to make the list Static but not help

**My Service**

```
 public interface INavigationService
{
  void PushDictionary(List<Word> allWordsOfUserForAutomat);
}
```

**My Implementation**

```
public class NavigationImplementation : Activities.INavigationService
 {
            public void PushDictionary(List<Word> allWordsOfUserForAutomat)  //HERE I SEE THE VALUE
          {
              Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.Instance,typeof(LockScreenDictionary));
            MainActivity.Instance.StartActivity(intent);
              
            }
}
```

**My standard**

```
protected void LockScreen()
  {
                    
     if (!viewDisabled)
       {
         DependencyService.Get<INavigationService>().PushDictionary(_allWordsOfUserForAutomat); //HERE I SEE THE VALUE
                     
        }
         else
        {
    NotificationService.ShowToast("Nothing to play");
        }
     }
```

**My droid project**

```
[Activity(Label = "LockScreenDictionary", Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash")]

 public class LockScreenDictionary : FormsAppCompatActivity
     {
    
      private List<Word> _allWordsOfUserForAutomat;  //HERE ITS NULL
      protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
       LangUpDictionaryPlayer.PlayAutomat(_allWordsOfUserForAutomat);  //HERE ITS NULL
       }
 }
```

Comment: What class implements `INavigationService`? Your `LockScreenDictionary` class as posted  does not implement `LockScreenDictionary `.

Comment: Sorry i was just editing the question and added that class

Comment: @Dai is my edit helpful ?

Comment: `PushDictionary` accepts a parameter value but then does nothing with it.

Comment: @Jason Yes i figured that out however i cant find a method that i could use i have found intent.PutStringArrayListExtra("MyData", allWordsOfUserForAutomat); However this method accepts IList<string> and i am trying to cast it but i am getting an error

Comment: there are numerous existing questions about passing data to an Intent

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the `allWordsOfUserForAutomat` to Intent:

In your Implementation:

```
public class NavigationImplementation : INavigationService
{
    public void PushDictionary(List<Word> allWordsOfUserForAutomat)  //HERE I SEE THE VALUE
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.Instance, typeof(LockScreenDictionary));
        //pass data
        intent.PutExtra("myData", allWordsOfUserForAutomat); 
        MainActivity.Instance.StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

In your droid project:

```
public class LockScreenDictionary : FormsAppCompatActivity
{

    private List<Word> _allWordsOfUserForAutomat;  //HERE ITS NULL
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        _allWordsOfUserForAutomat = Intent.Extras.GetInt("myData");

        LangUpDictionaryPlayer.PlayAutomat(_allWordsOfUserForAutomat);  //HERE ITS NULL
    }
}
```